# Using script to save dynamic network ip address to file?

Tags: ip, applescript, ip-address, appleevents

Is there a way I could use AppleScript to **check for my network ip address**? Or an alternative coding option? I need to save the ip address to a file if it has changed and then upload it to my ftp server with a date and time stamp. I have this part figured out its just checking for the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ifconfig.me just returns a plain text public IP:

```
do shell script "curl ifconfig.me > ip.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set filePath to POSIX path of ((path to desktop as text) & "myIp.txt")
set myIp to do shell script "curl checkip.dyndns.org | grep -Eo [0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+ > " & quoted form of filePath
```